# Squid4 forward proxy to upgrade from ws to wss

Tags: websocket, squid, gorilla

Squid4.6 is used as a forward proxy to convert all traffic to secure traffic. 
The configuration of squid is very simple, it allows all traffic and uses urlrewrite.pl to replace "http" to "https".(SSL-BUMP is NOT used) Squid proxy has tls_outgoing_options set, so the following works:

client(http) -----> Squid ------> Server(https)

Now, I am trying to replicate the same with websockets.
There are 3 test cases,
1. 
   client(ws)------> Squid -----> Server(ws)

2. client(wss) ------> Squid -----> Server(wss)

3 
   client(ws) ------> Squid -----> Server(wss)

The first two cases work with squid, but the third one does not work. And I only need the third option.
I have given debug logs for urlrewrite.pl to show the exact request received for a websocket connection, and the following is the log: 
Here port 8080: is server and port 3128: is squid

DEBUG:root:localhost:8080 127.0.0.1/localhost - CONNECT myip=127.0.0.1 myport=3128

Even wireshark shows the same,
1. CONNECT HTTP 1.1
2. GET
3. upgrade protocol.

Question: 
1.Is there any way to upgrade a websocket connection to secure websocket using squid4.6?
2.Or say I use wss-client (without certificate) and a wss-server(with certificates), is there a way to inform squid to use its own certificates even mentioned in "tls_outgoing_options" to establish the connection?

REQUIRED: 
Client will always send a unsecure traffic HTTP/WS 
and Squid should upgrade it to HTTPS/WSS.
In our application setup, we use our own openssl libraries to create certificates - which cannot be included in the (client.go) go-tls package, so we use squid proxy to use the certificates generated by our own openssl libraries. 
Client and Forward-Proxy (Squid) are both in our specific environment, so squid.conf is very simple and allows all traffic.
And we need mutual cert authentication.

SQUID CONF CODE

```
#
# Recommended minimum configuration:
#

# Example rule allowing access from your local networks.
# Adapt to list your (internal) IP networks from where browsing
# should be allowed
acl localhost src 127.0.0.1

acl SSL_ports port 443
acl Safe_ports port 443 # https
acl Safe_ports port 80  # http
acl CONNECT method CONNECT

http_access deny !Safe_ports
http_access deny CONNECT !SSL_ports
http_access allow localhost
http_access deny all

# Squid normally listens to port 3128
http_port 3128

url_rewrite_program /etc/squid/urlrewrite.pl
url_rewrite_access allow  all
tls_outgoing_options cert=/etc/squid/proxy.crt
tls_outgoing_options key=/etc/squid/proxy.key
tls_outgoing_options cafile=/etc/squid/serverauth.crt
```

urlrewrite CODE

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
select(STDOUT);
$| = 1;
while (<>) {
    #print STDOUT "OK rewrite-url=\"https://google.com\"\n";

    if (/^(|\d+\s+)((\w+):\/+)([^\/:]+)(|:(\d+))(|\/\S*)(|\s.*)$/) {
        my $channel = $1;
        my $protocolClean = $3;
        my $domain = $4;
        my $port = $5;
        my $portClean = $6;
        my $urlPath = $7;

    if ($protocolClean eq 'http' ){#&& ($port eq '' || $portClean eq '80')) {
           print STDOUT "${channel}OK rewrite-url=\"https://${domain}${port}${urlPath}\"\n";
       #print STDOUT "${channel}OK rewrite-url=\"https://google.com\"\n";
    } else {
           print STDOUT "${channel}ERR\n";
    }
    }
}
```